Connection refused when other devices first join the network
I have a newly installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on a machine on my home network, with other devices trying to connect to it. It has ufw running allowing certain ports to be accessible, and has DHCP reservation from the router so it always has the same static IP
Whenever a device joins the network, regardless of whether the other device is booted up or just turning off and on WIFI, the Ubuntu machine will refuse to be connected to (note the Ubuntu machine remains online the entire time). This is regardless of the port/services that the other devices is trying to reach. For example, when SSHing onto the machine, it gives operation timed out. However, after a short period of refusing, network connection suddenly can be established, and new connection can be made as long as there is one active connection between the devices. That is, if I can SSH onto the machine with one device, I can also visit a webpage on port 80 with the same device. If all connection are dropped between the device, after a period of time this behaviour will repeat (i.e. refusing connection a few times then accept connection as long as they are already connected or recently connected)
Reading some other post, I have tried looking at the logs of ufw and NetworkManager, but nothings has point to the issue. This behaviour is also only observed on this Ubuntu machine, with other (mostly Windows) devices on the network not experiencing the same issue
